# AJAX request returning unicode characters as question marks

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, unicode

I have the following PHP script being called by AJAX:

```
<?php
    // file /ajax/loopback.php
    $fp = fopen("php://input","r");
    $pdt = "";
    while(!feof($fp)) $pdt .= fgets($fp);
    fclose($fp);
    $_POST = json_decode($pdt,true);
    if( !$_POST) $_POST = Array();

    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
?>
```

I then call this script with the following JavaScript:

```
AJAX = function(url,data,callback) {
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if( data) {
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    a.open("POST","/ajax/"+url,true);
    a.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( a.readyState == 4) {
            if( a.status == 200) {
                callback(JSON.parse(a.responseText));
            }
        }
    };
    a.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    a.send(data);
};

AJAX("loopback.php",{name:'ヴィックサ'},alert);
```

The expected result is an alert box containing:

```
Array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "ヴィックサ"
}
```

(or maybe "string(10)" due to multibyte characters)
But the result I'm getting is:

```
Array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "?????"
}
```

What am I missing to allow Unicode characters to be passed via AJAX?

**EDIT:** I've added some code to show me what the raw post data is, and it seems like the `?????` is there in the raw post data, ie. the Unicode isn't even making it to the server.

Comment: Yes, I tried with and without. It made no difference, though...

Comment: If you call the file directly without using AJAX does it output the same - question marks?

Comment: If I try submitting that data through a `form`, the resulting string is 40 characters long, a set of five HTML entities (`&#_____;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your page that has the JavaScript (or that is loading the JavaScript file) are you setting the charset to UTF-8?

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Try looking at your script in Firebug, and make sure the characters in this line...

```
AJAX("loopback.php",{name:'ヴィックサ'},alert);
```

look the same in your source file as they do in the debugger.

( at least, I tried your script and it worked fine for me as soon as I set the character encoding. )

Comment: Yes, I made sure the character set was correct both in the Javascript and in the HTML, as well as the PHP. I probably did something wrong though. I've decided it's not a big deal really, since it'll be a primarily English site and if people *really* want special characters outside the first 255, they can learn all about HTML entities and use them. Thanks for the answer, though.