# question marks instead of russian characters

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I send such `post` request

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'loadallevents.html',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(data) {
        //var data = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            alert(item.description);
            $("#latest_events").append(template1);
        });
    }
});
```

This is my server code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loadallevents.html", produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String loadAllEvents(Model model) {
    logger.debug("attempt to load all events with new objects");
    List<Event> es = eventService.findAllEvents();
    Gson gson = new Gson();    

    logger.debug("Size of list: " + es.size());
    String res = gson.toJson(es);
    logger.debug(res);
    return res;
}
```

But in the result I have for example `"description" : "??????? Java"` and etc.
What's the problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX request returning unicode characters as question marks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774959/ajax-request-returning-unicode-characters-as-question-marks)

Comment: @TiesonT. My jsp has `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` and I use java and not php so I can't set `header` like in the answer

Comment: As long as you have the `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' in your page content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>` it should be okay

Comment: The problem is that it isn't okay